# Conditional expectation with sympy

Tags: probability, sympy

How can I calculate the conditional expectation of a random variable in sympy? I read [this](https://www.computer.org/cms/ComputingNow/homepage/2012/0712/W_CS_SymbolicStatisticswithSymPy.pdf) and tried:

```
from sympy.stats import *
v = Uniform("v",0,1)
E(v)
```

this returns correctly 1/2, but then:

```
E(v, v>1/2)
```

returns NaN. I also tried:

```
E(v, where(v > 1/2))
```

it returned 1/2, which is incorrect (it should be 3/4).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue (which I see you [already reported](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/13324)) is specific to  uniformly distributed random variables. (There's also an [older issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/11258) involving Uniform.) For other distributions, what you did works correctly:

```
>>> from sympy.stats import *
>>> x = Exponential("x", 1)
>>> E(x, x < 2)
-3/(-1 + exp(2)) + exp(2)/(-1 + exp(2))
```

As for the uniform type, a workaround for now is to remember that conditioning a uniformly distributed random variable to some interval creates another uniformly distributed random variable.

So the value of `E(v, v > 1/2)` can be found by computing

```
E(Uniform("x", 1/2, 1))
```

which returns 0.75.

---

Caution: if working interactively, one may want to eventually import from core SymPy, in addition to its stats module. Since E stands for Euler's number 2.718... in SymPy, one may end up unable to compute expectations with

> TypeError: 'Exp1' object is not callable

So one either has to be more specific about what to import, or use namespace for one or both modules. My preferred solution is

```
from sympy import *
import sympy.stats as st
```

So that `st.E` is expectation while `E` is 2.718...