# TypeError when determining density of z = Uniform(0,1) * Uniform(1,2) in sympy

Tags: python, plot, sympy

I'm working with a two uniform distributions and want to plot the probability density function of `z = U[0, 1] * U[1, 2]`. However, I get a TypeError when trying to plot the density function of mixture `u1 * u2`.

```py
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.stats import Uniform, density
from sympy.plotting import plot

u1 = Uniform("u1", 0, 1)
u2 = Uniform("u2", 1, 2)
u3 = u1 * u2
x = symbols('x')

p1 = plot(density(u1)(x), (x, 0, 2), line_color='C0', show=False)
p2 = plot(density(u2)(x), (x, 0, 2), line_color='C1', show=False)
p1.extend(p2)
p1.show()  # works as expected
```

The failure occurs when trying to add the third plot:

```
p3 = plot(density(u3)(x), (x, 0, 2), line_color='C2', show=False)
```

Trying this regularly gives me `TypeError cannot determine truth value of Relational`

I've also tried it with `density(u3, evaluate=False)` which I found as a suggestion somewhere, but then I get `TypeError: can't convert expression to float`.

```
p3 = plot(density(u3, evaluate=False)(x), (x, 0, 2), line_color='C2', show=False)
```

Is this the right way to try to plot this density function?

If so, what am I doing wrong?

If not, how can I plot this instead?

Comment: Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46293837/conditional-expectation-with-sympy/46391994#46391994 ?

Comment: @JohanC I don't see how that question is relevant, I'm not working with conditional evaluation or the expectation. Calling the expectation seems to works fine btw: E(u3) gives 3/4. If anything, I think it's more likely to have to do something with this open issue: github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/17321

Comment: Based what I found at [GitHub issue 17321](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/17321), this is now raised as [GitHub issue 19941](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/19941).